# Compatible SBT Version for Play 2.6 and Scala 2.12

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am using play 2.16.13 and Scala 2.12.6.
I am able to use SBT 0.13.8 and trying to upgrade to next version.

While using SBT 1.3.10, getting some error as below, Can someone please let me know the compatible version of SBT for the above mentioned play and scala.

[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.apache.commons/commons-parent/39/
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/commons-io/commons-io/2.5/jars/common
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/run-support_2.10/2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because there was a older sbt used and i upgraded to a newer one. After deleting the .ivy2 and .sbt folder, it started working with latest sbt